# Typescript ensure object value are not date

Tags: typescript

I have the following typings

```
export interface KDocumentContent {
    _kuzzle_info?: KDocumentKuzzleInfo;
}
export type GenericState = { device: KDocumentContent; server: KDocumentContent };

export interface DeviceFactory<
  State extends GenericState = GenericState,
  Events extends GenericDeviceIOEvents = { in: any; out: any },
>
```

I want to restrict State from DeviceFactory to have an object with values of type Date because I want to force the user to play with timestamp instead, which allows me to bypass date conversion after deserializing.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Can you help me on that? Thanks

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2QerW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?